# Is there tools to define Rest API in document ?

Tags: api, rest, web

Many questions being asked about generate Rest API to html documents.

But eggs comes from chicken.

In many cases , the architecture needs to define the API . It's a connection between web developers and iOS/Android client developers.

So is there such kind of tool or web , we can do follow things:

New a API
write the subURL
write the POST/GET method
write the post parameters
write the returned answers
write the sample request , any kinds of condition, error codes.
After all this, there is a doc or Online doc html there.

We can edit , update it after times pass by. The web/client developer , just need to watch the document ,then they are ready to go.

Is there any kind of tool can archive this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of specs for documents that allow clients to discover RESTful APIs.

- [**Swagger**](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki) ([demo](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/#!/user))
- [**apiary**](http://apiary.io/)
- [**JSON Home**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-json-home-02)
- Google use their own [**Discovery Service**](https://developers.google.com/discovery/), however unlike the others, unfortunately I don't think there are open sourced libraries that help you use expose it from your own APIs.

I have used swagger and it works well. The spec handles the things you have mentioned:

- JSON Schema to describe request/responses
- A list of error codes/conditions
- A [codegen library](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen) to generate client side code for a number of languages such as Javascript, Java, Objective-C, Scala, PHP, Python, Ruby, and more.

Comment: swagger didn't design api. It just generate the API from exsiting code , but code should come after design API document released.

Comment: Swagger comes in a few parts. A document you use to describe/design your API (see [here](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/API-Declaration)), an app that uses that api document to create human readable web UI (see demo [here](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/#!/user) and code [here](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui)) and finally the [codegen library](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen) that uses the api document to generate code. At my work we add API calls to the swagger document before implementing it.